# How to get account creation age discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a bot and I would like to make a command which tells me the account age of the user. For example: 2 years, 3 months, 3 days. I have tried using this code below but got nowhere.

```
@client.command()
async def joined(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    duration = datetime.datetime.now()  

    hours, remainder = divmod(int(duration .total_seconds()), 3600)
    years, months = divmod(remainder, I don't know what goes here)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)

    await ctx.send(f"Joined {years} year(s), {months} month(s), {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s")
```

Any help is appreiated, thanks!

Comment: Did it occur to you that, given that `member` is the member whose age you want to determine, that the code should use it somewhere? It's an instance of `discord.Member`, right? So, what happened when you tried looking up the `discord.Member` class in the documentation? Also, what happened when you tried using a search engine to get help with this? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users .